# Magento include a custom block on every page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

On my magento site I want to include a custom block on every page. This block will follow some logic and decide if it should trigger a lightbox popup or not.

Whats the best way to include my block on every page? Or is there a better solution to this?

Basically the block will either run some JS to trigger the popup, or do nothing, depending on if it is A enabled and B a set number of page views has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Create an event observer for the `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` event, and then in your observer method use the Magento `core/layout` object to get reference to the `content` block (or `before_body_end`, or any of the `text/list` containers), and then `append` a new block (created with `createBlock`) to this block.

If you're unclear on the Magento terminology above, google searches and specific, targeted questions here and on the Magento Stack Exchange will get you where you need to be.

Good luck!